# Struts 2 "%" sign and '#" sign in OGNL

Tags: java, struts2, ognl

Anybody can tell me how to use "%" and "#" sign in STRUTS2 OGNL? I google around, but can't find any valuable info about this.Or give me a link of documentation of this.

thanks

Answer (score 19):

The `%` character forces OGNL evaluation, so `<s:property name="%{foo}"/>` will query the stack for a `foo` property. It's not always required (rarely, in fact), but it's easier to use it consistently for clarity.

The `#` character accesses a *named* value stack context variable, for example, you used to need it to access a variable created using the `<s:set>` tag. You need it to access things like a session variable, like `<s:property name="#session.user.name"/>`.

- [S2 OGNL Docs](https://struts.apache.org/docs/ognl.html)
- [S2-specific OGNL Docs](https://struts.apache.org/docs/ognl-basics.html)
- [OGNL reference docs](http://commons.apache.org/ognl/language-guide.html)

Comment: First two links are broken now :(

Comment: @RaviGupta I've updated the links, but remember that on SO the users are empowered to make edits, or edit suggestions if their reputation isn't at the edit level yet.

Comment: Thanks Dave, for some reasons I was not able to search for the correct links yesterday.