# Struts 2 - The usage of %{ } notation

Tags: java, web-applications, struts2, ognl, webwork

What is the exact use of `%{}` notation in Struts 2? Can someone explain with a simple example where the code works when `%{}` is used and does not works when its not used?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824576/struts-2-sign-and-sign-in-ognl/7824666#7824666

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used in OGNL to force evaluate the content in brackets as OGNL expression. For example

```
<s:iterator value = "myAnswers" status="stat">
<s:textfield name = "myAnswers[%{#stat.index}].name"/>
```

evaluation of the `stat.index` should be forced.

Comment: https://securitylab.github.com/research/apache-struts-double-evaluation be careful of forced evaluations

Comment: @Rogit In this example forced evaluation is safe and used only once, but for different things.