# Struts 2 tags seem to evaluate inconsistently

Tags: tags, struts2, ognl

I have an issue with some Struts2 tags mixed with OGNL. To overcome the fact that you cannot nest evaluation of expressions in OGNL, e.g., `%{foo[%{bar}]}`, I use successive assignment to variables to get the results that I need.

In the following code, the var `grpIndex` evaluates correctly, e.g., `'6'` or `'7'` in my case, and prints out correctly on the next line. The following statement (line 3) also evaluates correctly, e.g., `'stage'` or `'prod'` in my case.

However, in the fourth line I try setting that same expression into a variable, using the same syntax as the previous line, so that I can use it in a title. To test this assignment, I try to print out the var on the next line. I would expect the last line to print the same value as the third line. However, this expression prints out nothing. Why is this?

```xml
<s:set var="grpIndex" value="%{options[#optstatus.index]}"/>
grpIndex = <s:property value="#grpIndex"/><br/>
grpName = <s:text name="model[%{grpIndex}].groupName"/><br/>
<s:set var="grpName" value="model[%{grpIndex}]).groupName"/>
groupName = <s:property value="#grpName"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not completely correct saying that *you cannot nest evaluation of expressions in OGNL*. If you look at the [Expression Evaluation](https://commons.apache.org/dormant/commons-ognl/language-guide.html#Expression_Evaluation) of the OGNL Language Gude, you will find that if you use parenthesized expression without a dot in front of the parentheses the result of evaluating that expression will be used as expression to be evaluated. See the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16716897/573032).

Second, I don't see the reason for which you are getting indexes other than iterator index.

Third, the `set` tag places variables to the *value stack context* that is accessible via `#` notation. See the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20845525/573032).

Fourth, answering your direct question:

Because a typo in the fourth line. Replace the line with

```
<s:set var="grpName" value="model[%{#grpIndex}].groupName"/>
```

will do what expected. You can see the differences in expression.

The last is just reference to show you where you should use `%{}` to force evaluation of expression, because Struts is parsing everything (by default) in the tag attributes for OGNL.

> [The usage of %{} notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18492714/573032):
>
> Used in OGNL to force evaluate the content in brackets as OGNL expression.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using `<s:text>` (line 3) instead of `<s:property>` which will yield a wrong test results. Second there is a typo in line 4 (unopened bracket). And most important don't use `%{}` inside `[]` in `<s:property>` or `<s:set>` tags.

```
<s:set var="grpIndex" value="options[#optstatus.index]"/>
grpIndex = <s:property value="#grpIndex"/><br/>
grpName = <s:property value="model[#grpIndex].groupName"/><br/>
<s:set var="grpName" value="model[#grpIndex].groupName"/>
groupName = <s:property value="#grpName"/>
```