# Understanding OGNL expressions in Struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl, valuestack

The following code displays links using `<s:a>` of Struts starting from 1 to 10.

```
<s:set var="currentPage" value="2"/>
<s:set var="begin" value="1"/>
<s:set var="end" value="10"/>

<s:iterator begin="%{begin}" end="%{end}" step="1" var="row" status="loop">
    <s:if test="%{#currentPage eq #row}">    <!--???-->
        <span><s:property value="%{#row}"/></span>
    </s:if>

    <s:else>
        <s:url id="pageURL" action="someAction" escapeAmp="false">
            <s:param name="currentPage" value="%{row}"/>
        </s:url>

        <s:a href="%{pageURL}" name="btnPage" cssClass="paging">
            <s:property value="%{#row}"/>
        </s:a>
    </s:else>
</s:iterator>
```

When `currentPage` (which is 2) matches the conditional expression `test="%{#currentPage eq #row}"`, it just displays text using `<s:property>` inside `<span>` instead of showing a link. That's fine.

---

When I use these same tags but using appropriate properties in its corresponding action class like so,

```
<s:iterator begin="%{begin}" end="%{end}" step="1" var="row" status="loop">
    <s:if test="%{currentPage eq #row}">   <!--???-->
        <span class="current"><s:property value="%{#row}"/></span>
    </s:if>

    <s:else>
        <s:url id="pageURL" action="someAction" escapeAmp="false">
            <s:param name="currentPage" value="%{row}"/>
        </s:url>

        <s:a href="%{pageURL}" name="btnPage" cssClass="paging">
            <s:property value="%{#row}"/>
        </s:a>
    </s:else>
</s:iterator>
```

In this case, `currentPage` (and all other) is a property of type `Long` in the action class. Here, the conditional test regarding the previous case which is `test="%{#currentPage eq #row}"` is evaluated to **false**.

It requires the omission of `#` before `currentPage`. Hence, the expression becomes `test="%{currentPage eq #row}"` (otherwise, it **always** evaluates to false).

I don't understand why does the first case require `test="%{#currentPage eq #row}"` and the second case require `test="%{currentPage eq #row}"`? Is there anything I might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `<s:set>` a value it's not *on* the value stack, but instead *in* the "value stack context".

Using the bare `currentPage` reference only searches the actual *stack*, not the context.

Using `#currentPage` doesn't check the stack itself, but instead references the stack *context*.

See these other answers as well:

1. [what's the difference between #{} ${} and %{}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421567/whats-the-difference-between-and/9421667#9421667)
2. [Struts 2 "%" sign and '#" sign in OGNL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824576/struts-2-sign-and-sign-in-ognl/7824666#7824666)

Comment: Are all action objects/variables stored into the value stack under `ActionContext`?

Comment: @Tiny The action itself is on the top of the stack (normally) once you hit the view layer, although you can put your own values on top of it, e.g., using `<s:push>` or `<s:iterator>` etc.

Comment: `Using the bare currentPage reference only searches the actual stack, not the value stack context` is not true.